# Undefined reference to a class method

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop

I have one class, Pose.hpp and Pose.cpp, and a main.cpp to use this, but when compile I'm getting error.
I'm using this to compile:

```
$g++ -c main.cpp
$g++ -c Pose.cpp
$g++ -o Pose.o main.o



// Pose.hpp

#include "Vec3f.hh"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;
class Pose
{
    Vec3f root_position;
    vector < Vec3f > bonesAngles;
    vector < Vec3f > bonesPosition;

    public:

    void setRootPosition (Vec3f position);
    void addBone (Vec3f newBone);
};

//Pose.cpp

#include "Pose.hpp"

using namespace std;

void Pose :: setRootPosition (Vec3f position)
{
    root_position = position;
}

void Pose :: addBone (Vec3f newBone)
{
    bonesAngles.push_back(newBone);
}

//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Pose.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Pose pose;
    Vec3f aux(.2,.3,.4);
    pose.addBone(aux);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the error:
/tmp/ccSzsctS.o:main.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'Pose::addBone(Vec3f)'

collect2: erro: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Now think about that. Read the manual of `gcc` and consider what `g++ -o Pose.o main.o` does. In particular, the meaning of the `-o` flag.

Comment: I was trying to compile and run like I do with one single file. It's the error? The code is right?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but the compiler invocation is clearly erroneous.

Comment: The problem was only the compile commands H2CO3. If you knew that was wrong, could be helped me rather than just said "It's wrong... " Like the user Brainless did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must compile a .o file for each .cpp. Try this :

> $g++ -c Pose.cpp -o Pose.o
>
> $g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
>
> $g++ -o Pose.o main.o MyProgram

The .o files are called "object" files, there will contain basically all the information for final compilation. In your case, you need the functions definitions (it's what your compile error says). Compiling as you did only checks that the syntax is correct.

There is 2 steps during compiling : compiling and linking. Compiling (with your command lines) is only checking that the syntax is correct basically. At the end of this step the object files are produced. Linking is using the object files (and possibly other types of files, like .dll, .lib) to create a final product (in your case an executable file, but you can produce many different other things, like .dll, .lib, .a, etc ...).

Understanding compilation is a critical step in programming, I invite you to get into it.

For a more detailed explanation, have a look at : [http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~jestes/howto/g++compiling.txt](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Ejestes/howto/g++compiling.txt)

Good luck !

Comment: `g++ >>-o<< Pose.o main.o MyProgram` sure?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's the difference between last line and this : g++ -o MyProgram Pose.o main.o  Maybe the latter will work

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. But I have to change the last command to $g++ -o MyProgram Pose.o main.o like in the tutorial link you sent me.